# How to set up sqlite android database

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm trying to implement an android app that uses a login feature. I'm a bit confused as to what database related classes I need? At the minute I have DBAdapter.java and DbHelper.java but I believe that only one is needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html ?

Comment: A database is using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.  `SharedPrerences` is a lot easier.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html This tutorial is detailed and will help you .

Comment: You can check this tutorial http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/24/android-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

using sharedpreferences for storing login values is much easier than constructing a database and a table then retrieve values and using cursors, so just go ahead with sharedpreferences and here is a good tutorial :http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

you don't need to implement the whole UI in this tutorial just take the sharedpreferences part and test it and use Log.d(String,String); or what ever method to print the output in your logcat or UI.

for a login scenario you need to store both the key and the value as a string where for example the username of the user will be the key and the password will be the value.

then you can use a method in sharedpreferences called getall() which returns all the values you stored in a map which you can loop through it and check if the user name(key) and password(value) entered by user are both equal to one of the map elements retrieved or not.